# how to go to datepickerview from date textfield?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to go to datepickerview from date textfield?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i got you right -

you should add the DatePickerView as the inputView of the textField.

```
   textField.inputView = datePickerView;
```

this line will make your app lunch the date picker when your text field is becoming the first responder.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Use text view delegate view methods

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

U can use the methods according to your needs and show the Picker view when u want, through those methods